# CreateFile returns invalid handle value

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to read file from the directory the exe file is located. The data.txt file is in VS Project directory and when I specify the full path everything works fine.

```
char curDirectory[MAX_PATH];
GetCurrentDirectory(MAX_PATH, curDirectory);

char filePath[MAX_PATH];

char *name = "\\data.txt";

memcpy(filePath, curDirectory, sizeof(curDirectory));
memcpy(filePath + strlen(curDirectory), name, strlen(name));

HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(filePath, GENERIC_ALL, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
```

Comment: Don't build file path strings using things like `memcpy()`. Use something more like `PathCombine()` instead. And `GetCurrentDirectory()` is not guaranteed to report the folder where the EXE resides. Use `GetModuleFileName()` instead and strip off the filename from it, such as with `PathRemoveFileSpec()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't null terminate the string. Do so by passing `strlen(name) + 1` in the second call to `memcpy`.

Some other observations:

- When `CreateFile` fails, you should call `GetLastError` to obtain an error code.
- Use `strcpy` and `strcat` rather than `memcpy` when working with strings.
- That said, your code asks to overrun the buffer. If this really is C++, use `std::string` and have that class manage buffers.
- There is no real reason to believe that the executable file is located in the current working directory.